# Passing array to Javascript function only passing first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

I am using the following code to pass an array to variable javascript functions

```
function parse(fn, args)
{
     var parameters = [];

     if (args)
     {
          for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {
               parameters.push(args[i]);
          }
     }

     fn = (typeof fn == "function") ? fn : window[fn];
     return fn.apply(this, parameters);
}

function SomeFunction(parameters)                                                                    
{
     console.log(parameters);                                                                        
}
```

This works, to an extent, as the right function is called and the parameters are passed to it. However, I only receive the first element of the array in the function, which is obviously the issue I am having as I need all the elements of the array not simply the first.

Comment: plead add a sample usage

Comment: `function SomeFunction(...parameters)` would work, but you are doing things backwards. Why `apply`, when you want the first parameter to be an array? Why not just `fn.call(this, parameters)`, when you expect one argument which is an array? Also, that for loop is quite verbose for `let parameters = Array.from(args);`

Comment: `someFunction` only has one parameter. When you use `apply()`, each array element becomes a separate parameter. So the first array element fills in the single `parameters` variable.

Comment: There's no need for the `for` loop to copy `args` to `parameters`. You can just do `var parameters = args || [];`

Comment: I am still learning javascript, having been a back end architect for years so I am doing this all from posts and the examples of others.. changing the parse function seems to have worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `...` (rest operator) for `parse` arguments, will simplify as well as passes array correctly.

```js
function parse(fn, ...parameters) {
  fn = typeof fn == "function" ? fn : window[fn];
  return fn.apply(this, parameters);
}

function SomeFunction(parameters) {
  console.log(parameters);
}

parse(SomeFunction, [1, 2]);
```